# Bash Iterate through repeated values in file

Tags: bash

I have a file with this format:

```
User_ID , Place_ID , Rating 
U32  ,   1305  ,   2 
U32  ,   1276  ,   2 
U32  ,   1789  ,   3 
U65  ,   1985  ,   1 
U65  ,   1305  ,   1 
U65  ,   1276  ,   2
```

I would like to iterate through this file, sort by `Place_ID`, iterate through repeated values in `Place_ID` and add the ratings, once the last element of the `Place_ID` is added, check if `value > x` and if true, push the `Place_ID` into an array.

Ex: Place_ID 1305: 2 + 1  / 2 = 1.5 > 1 ----> ids+=($id)

Place_ID 1276: 2 + 2 / 2 = 2 > 1 -----> ids+=($id)

I have tried with

```
test5 () {

id=0
count=0
rating=0
ids=()
ratings=()
for i in `sort -t',' -k 2 ratings.csv`
do  
    aux=`echo "$i"| cut -f2 -d','`
    if (( $id != $aux )); then
        if (( $rating != 0 )); then
            rating=`echo "scale=1; $rating / $count" | bc -l`
            if (( $(echo "$rating >= 1" | bc -l) )); then
                ids+=($id)
                ratings+=($rating)
            fi
        fi
        id=$aux
        count=0
        rating=0
    else                        
        rating=$(($rating + `echo "$i"| cut -f3 -d','`))
        count=$(($count + 1))
    fi
done

echo ${#ids[@]}
echo ${#ratings[@]}
}
```

EDIT: I think it works, but is there a way to make it better? Something that doesn't force me to use as many if's and count.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This sounds like a bad fit for Bash, but a very good fit for Awk.

Comment: Your code seems to be meant for a comma-delimited file, not a pipe-delimited file like in your example data.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use Awk. True, sorry, going to edit the data.

Comment: Is specifically Awk off limits, or are you not allowed to use Python, Perl, Ruby etc either? That sounds like a really bad assignment; use the correct tool for the job.

Comment: I'm limited to Bash only. Unfortunately.

Comment: @RogerPiera I'm a bit confused, you say you are limited to bash, but call `sort` -- why couldn't you also call `awk` from your script? It's just another utility. (you could use it to fill `ids` and `ratings`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It's a limitation imposed in this assignment. I don't like it, but it's what it is.

Comment: I gotcha, nothing wrong with that, good educational value. But... understand, you are spawning a subshell for every call to `sort, cut, bc` (that's up to 3 subshells per-iteration or 18 for a 6 line file) where you could fill both `ids` and `ratings` with 2 calls to `awk` total. While it is good educational value, going forward know you want to avoid spawning subshells within a loop -- for large files, that is what really slows things down.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for that, useful to know. The file I use has 700+ entries, so I definitely noted the long time I need to execute this script.

Comment: @RogerPiera compare the run time with [arrays filled with `awk`](http://paste.opensuse.org/91156827).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another option using less `if`'s:

```
#!/bin/bash

sum=()
count=()

while read -r line; do

    place=$(echo "$line" | cut -d',' -f2)
    rating=$(echo "$line" | cut -d',' -f3)

    sum[$place]=$(echo "$rating + ${sum[$place]-0}" | bc -l)
    count[$place]=$((count[$place] + 1))

done < <( sed 1d ratings.csv | sort -t',' -k 2 | tr -d '[:blank:]' )

ratings=()
for place in "${!sum[@]}"; do
    ratings[$place]=$(echo "scale=1; ${sum[$place]} / ${count[$place]}" | bc -l)
done

# ratings at this point has the ratings for each place
echo ${!ratings[@]} # place ids
echo ${ratings[@]} # ratings
```

I'm assuming your `ratings.csv` has headers that is why this has `sed 1d ratings.csv`